# Force text input to all caps before sending to controller MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have this textbox in the Index() view for users to enter an ID that gets sent to a controller method to look up a consultant in the database based on the ID, but I want to force the input to be capitalized before it's sent to the controller. I know I can just capitalize it inside the controller method, but the Consultant object that gets created has the lowercase ID if the user entered it with lowercase initially, and for some reason a modal popup I have for editing consultant details in a different view, ViewConsultant,  is pulling in the original lowercase ID instead of the uppercase one that's attached to the model. I hope this question makes sense, I can clarify if I didn't make clear what my issue is.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control " id="ID" name="ID" style="vertical-align:bottom; text-transform:uppercase;" />
```

Comment: `I can just capitalize it inside the controller method, but the Consultant object that gets created has the lowercase ID if the user entered it with lowercase initially` - then you are doing it wrong.  You could rely on JavaScript to do this, but clients can turn that off / alter the input using built in tools.  Server-side is the only way to guarantee always upper case. In your controller, ensure you are properly setting a new variable when you call `string.ToUpper()` such as `var upperCaseId = Id.ToUpper();` and ensure you pass the `upperCaseId` to your SQL statement and not the original Id.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. The ConsultantModel parameter that gets passed to the ViewConsultant() controller method has a lowercase ID if the user entered it as lowercase initially. I can change that inside the method easily and look up the consultant with no issue. And the model I send to the ViewConsultant view even has it capitalized. The issue that arises is in a modal popup for editing consultant details. I have a hidden ID textbox there and that specific one is getting the original lowercase ID instead of the capital one from the model. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Can you show your methods for `ViewConsultant()` and the `Search()` (or whatever action users are using to type a consultant Id) controller methods?

Answer (score 0):

By lower and upper case IDs, I think you are talking about the property names?  One technique I tend to use on my view models it to have a complex property on the root for the main view, and one for the modal (or at least one complex property for the modal).

I do the following:

```
public class RootViewModel
{

   public long ID { get; set; }

   public string OtherData { get;set; }

   public ModalDetails ModalDetails { get;set; }

}

public class ModalDetails
{
   public long ID { get; set; }

   public string OtherData { get; set; }
}
```

In the UI then you can do things like:

```
<form>
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
</form>

<div class="modal fade">
 ..
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ModalDetails.ID)
</div>
```

That way, the modal data is separate from the main view data.  If the modal has a form around it, you can also detect that the modal posted back because the ModalDetails record will be populated on postback, and things like that.